# Does deleteCell cause a pseudo-leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

According to [this website](http://outofhanwell.com/ieleak/index.php?title=Fixing_Leaks) calling [removeChild()](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_removechild.asp) in JavaScript causes an Internet Explorer Specific leak called a pseudo-leak.

> Sometimes Internet Explorer keeps items in memory after the page is done using them. Although these pseudo-leaks are freed after the user leaves the page, some web pages may be open for long periods of time. To avoid pseudo-leaks, do not use removeChild to remove elements. Instead, set the parent's innerHTML to ""

Does [deleteCell()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_tablerow_deletecell.asp) cause pseudo-leaks the same way that removeChild() does?

Edit: I was able to reproduce this error on IE8.  Believe it or not, Microsoft claims to have fixed this problem in IE7.

Comment: Without knowing what this deleteCell function is/does, impossible to answer. it's not a standard JS function.

Comment: @MarcB It is defined on [row elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTableRowElement), in the same category as `insertCell`, `insertRow` etc.

Comment: @Rob W: obviously my google-fu has failed me today... I blame Mondays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the benefit of being able to look at IE's source code and confirm, but I imagine if it's anything like how Chrome implements deleteCell, it uses removeChild internally, which could trigger IE's pseudo leak. I know older versions of IE had this issue, but I'm not sure if the current versions do.

From chromium source:

```
void HTMLTableRowElement::deleteCell(int index, ExceptionCode& ec)
{
        ...
        HTMLElement::removeChild(cell.get(), ec);
}
```

Comment: calling removeChild() inside deleteCell() seems like evidence enough for me.  As long as it is called inside some browsers, then I probably need to worry about it.